# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'

Tags: python

I try to run couchpotato, but somehow I get this error after I rebooted and updated. I have no clue how to solve it. I already tried reinstalling OpenSSL and updating python, but now luck.

```
mediaserver@mediaserver:~$ python /opt/couchpotato/CouchPotato.py --daemon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/couchpotato/CouchPotato.py", line 133, in <module>
    l = Loader()
  File "/opt/couchpotato/CouchPotato.py", line 35, in __init__
    from couchpotato.runner import getOptions
  File "/opt/couchpotato/couchpotato/runner.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/opt/couchpotato/libs/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/opt/couchpotato/libs/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 53, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/couchpotato/CouchPotato.py", line 133, in <module>
    l = Loader()
  File "/opt/couchpotato/CouchPotato.py", line 35, in __init__
    from couchpotato.runner import getOptions
  File "/opt/couchpotato/couchpotato/runner.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/opt/couchpotato/libs/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/opt/couchpotato/libs/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 53, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

Comment: Still no solution found.. :(

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an error existent in older `pyopenssl` versions, in combination with changes in other related packages. There are a couple of bug reports relating to it (like https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=843631). Most people seem get it to work using a more recent version of pyopenssl. In order to not break your systems built in python packages, install new version of pyopenssl without sudo:

```
# if you need it for python3:
pip3 install pyopenssl

# or for python2:
pip install pyopenssl
```